# MongoDB Query Issues

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mongodb which has many documents. Using Studio 3T I can see the document looks like below

```
{
   "DialectType" : "ORACLE",
   "DomainName" : "NewDomain"
}
```

There are many of this type with different values but with same keys. I am using below code to query the documents-

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("DialectType").is("ORACLE"));
mongoOperations.find(query, DialectTypeCollection.class, "my_collection_name");
```

The above query does not return records. I am not sure what is the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks pretty damn correct. Are you sure you are accessing the right database and collection? No typos anywhere? How do you instantiate the `mongoOperations` variable?

Comment: yes, everything is correct. When in the query I am giving "dialectType" with small 'd'. The query is working fine. Seems like Mongo DB converts the document keys into camel case with starting letter small while storing.

Comment: MongoDB does not convert anything. It could be, however, that Spring does some magic here. Are you using any custom type mapping? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.type-mapping